# Angular mat-icon does not load icon when custom global font family applied

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am having an angular build which I use as a lib. In this lib I use the mat-icon as the following.

```
<button>
    <mat-icon>
        edit
    </mat-icon>
    Edit
</button>
```

It works as exspected, so the button is created with the edit icon and the text on the button. But when I changed the global font family the mat-icon does not show the icon, it just displays its text "edit".

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MetaWebNormal;
    src: url("assets/fonts/MetaWeb-Normal.woff") format("woff");
}

* {
    font-family: 'MetaWebNormal' !important;
}
```

How can I fix the bug so that the mat-icon still knows which icon it shell load?

Comment: @LGuthardt have you add this `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">` is index file

Comment: @Abhishek For sure I did. As I said, the button with the icon works fine. It just does not display the icon **when I changed the global font family**. After changing that it just shows it's text "edit".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its because you have overriden icon-font family classes with your own using

`font-family: 'MetaWebNormal' !important`

Doing so, browser will no longer be able to use font-icons set in required places.

Don't use `!important` (as it force override given property even if it is set directly on given element which has top precedence), or exclude mat-icons from that rule.

Bonus:

I just tested and and it works

```
*{
   This breaks the icons
  /* font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important; */
}

   But this does not
*:not(mat-icon){
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif !important;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cfp7qg?file=app/icon-svg-example.css